# module 'scapy' has no attribute 'IP' (Or 'TCP') even when "from scapy.all import *" is used

Tags: python, scapy

```
def send(ip, port):
   ip_layer = scapy.IP()
   tcp_layer = scapy.TCP()
```

With scapy 2 and forwards, `from scapy.all import *` is instead used to import everything.
I did import scapy that way, but an attribute error occurs: `module 'scapy' has no attribute 'IP'`

Why is it happening? and how can I fix the code accordingly?

Comment: If you put `from scapy.all import *` then you don't need the `scapy.` prefix. Just do: `ip_layer = IP()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use
`from scapy.layers.inet import *`